# Send multiple response using Express.JS for vector tiles

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, openlayers, vector-tiles

I am creating vector tiles using PostgreSQL, Node.JS, and OpenLayers.Currently, I am able to create multilayer vector tiles using data stored in PostgreSQL but I think the process which I am following is repetitive and not sure that is the right way to do it. currently, when I run the server it loads all the layers one by one on map. Is there any way I can load all the layers simultaneously?

code:

```
// mercator
var SphericalMercator = require('@mapbox/sphericalmercator');
var mercator = new SphericalMercator({size: 256})

// database library
var {Client} = require('pg')
var db = new Client('postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/vtiles');
db.connect();

// http server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// roads
var layerName1 = 'roads';
app.get(`/tiles/${layerName1}/:z/:x/:y.mvt`, async (req, res) => {
  var bbox = mercator.bbox(req.params.x, req.params.y, req.params.z, false);
  var query = `
      SELECT ST_AsMVT(q, '${layerName1}', 4096, 'geom') FROM (
        SELECT 
          osm_id, name, type,
          ST_AsMVTGeom(
            geom,
            ST_MakeEnvelope(${bbox[0]}, ${bbox[1]}, ${bbox[2]}, ${bbox[3]}, 4326),
            4096,
            256,
            true
          ) geom FROM ${layerName1} WHERE type IS NOT NULL
        ) q
    `;
  try {
    
    var tiles = await db.query(query);
    var tile = tiles.rows[0];
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
    if (tile.st_asmvt.length === 0) {
      res.status(204);
    }
    res.send(tile.st_asmvt);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).send({ error: err.toString() });
  }
});

// buildings
var layerName2 = 'buildings';
app.get(`/tiles/${layerName2}/:z/:x/:y.mvt`, async (req, res) => {
  var bbox = mercator.bbox(req.params.x, req.params.y, req.params.z, false);
  var query = `
      SELECT ST_AsMVT(q, '${layerName2}', 4096, 'geom') FROM (
        SELECT 
          osm_id, name, type,
          ST_AsMVTGeom(
            geom,
            ST_MakeEnvelope(${bbox[0]}, ${bbox[1]}, ${bbox[2]}, ${bbox[3]}, 4326),
            4096,
            256,
            true
          ) geom FROM ${layerName2} WHERE type IS NOT NULL
        ) q
    `;
  try {
    
    var tiles = await db.query(query);
    var tile = tiles.rows[0];
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
    if (tile.st_asmvt.length === 0) {
      res.status(204);
    }
    res.send(tile.st_asmvt);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).send({ error: err.toString() });
  }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vector Tile Example</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        </div>
    <script>
      var tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        //source: new ol.source.Stamen({ layer: 'terrain-background' })
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })

      var vectorLayer1 = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
        source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
          format: new ol.format.MVT(),
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/tiles/roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt'
        }),
        style: function(feature) {
          return new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.5)',
              width: ['step', ['zoom'], 0.4, 14, 1, 16, 2, 18, 4, 20, 8]
            })
          })
        }
      })

      var vectorLayer2 = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
        source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
          format: new ol.format.MVT(),
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/tiles/buildings/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt'
        }),
        style: function(feature) {
          return new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.5)',
              width: ['step', ['zoom'], 0.4, 14, 1, 16, 2, 18, 4, 20, 8]
            })
          })
        }
      })
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [tileLayer, vectorLayer1,vectorLayer2],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([103.8198,1.3521]),
          zoom: 13
        })
      })
    
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "load all the layers simultaneously"? .. both vector layers as one?

Comment: Not as one layer . I have total 8 layers which i want to display on map so i have to repeat the same query 8 times. I want to do is that after running the query it should send all the response in parallel not one after one .

Comment: Sorry for the delay .. Two comments, 1) I think that the way you are doing is the common way to solve it, ie. one endpoint for each tile service (because you discard group layer), and map control taking care of the requests, 2) I don't think that you can parallelize, you are bound to the single thread, besides, I am not sure that even if you could do it (somehow), you will actually have any considerable gain .. But maybe I am not fully understanding your point

Comment: Currently i am generating diff mvt services for diff layers rather then would like to generate one mvt service which includes all the layers like the way google maps and osm has.so would like to create one app.get(`/tiles/:z/:x/:y.mvt`, async (req, res) and send all queries response using this .

Comment: OK, so you want to build a group layer. What I am saying is that depend on what you want to achieve is better one way or the other, it is more a trade off. For example, if you just want to show the layers as one, I mean the user would not be able to turn on/off the visibility, then is probably the right solution. There is not one best solution, depends on the needs.

Comment: @cabesuon yes, I want to show it as one layer but I am unable to do it.can you please guide me on how I can do it or some reference or some sample code.